# Как правильно писать слово "дни" в данном предложении?

Tags: орфография

Данный показатель составил 4,8 дня (дней?) в году, а республиканский показатель - 10,6 дня (дней), пропущенных (-нного) по болезни.

Answer (score 1):

10 целых 6 десятых (частей чего?) дня, 4 целых 8 десятых дня.  Существительным управляет дробь, а не целое число.

Comment: А как быть со второй частью - "пропущенного"?

Comment: Согласен с ответом, а затем идет слово "пропущенных" , так как дней здесь пропущено много

Comment: Простите, не заметила. Я бы тогда порядок слов изменила. Для корректной правки хорошо бы знать предыдущее предложение.